# Laravel - Validar datos recibidos en el controlador

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, php7, laravel-blade, laravel-6

tengo este método en el controlador que recibe una serie de datos del request y crea un registro.

```
    public function userCreate(Request $request): JsonResponse
{

    $input = $request->all();

    $validator = Validator::make($input, [
        'user_id' => 'integer',
        'name' => 'string',
        'age' => 'integer',
        'email' => 'required|unique:users,email',
    ]);

    if($validator->fails()){
        return $this->jsonValidatorFailedResponse($validator->errors());
    }

    $user = User::create($input);

    return response()->json($user);

}
```

Este código funciona correctamente, si todos los campos són completados crea el registro y si un campo no es del tipo esperado devuelve un error.

Un ejemplo de error seria este

**El campo age debe ser un número.**

Esto me lo devuelve en castellano porque en resources\lang\es he puesto los archivos en dicho idioma, pero si os fijais "age" es el nombre al que pertenece mi campo en el modelo.

Suelo siempre trabajar con nomenclaturas en inglés, a pesar de que mis frontales son en español.

Entonces mi pregunta es como puedo hacer para modificar la respuesta del error devuelta?
Aunque es cierto que en el controlador solo le envio el nombre del request en inglés...con lo que no se me ocurre como plantear esto.

Gracias.

Comment: Yo te aconsejo modularizar  tus funciones y separarlas de tus controladores. Aislalas en la clase correspondiente, que hagan algo concreto. Finalmente llama esas funciones de las clases en lso controladores y es en este en el q debe "controlar" que hacer en cada situacion

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#customizing-the-error-messages

Answer (score 0):

los textos de la clase Validator se encuentran:
resources/lang/es-en ... /validation.php, ahí puedes cambiar el texto que devuelve para cada regla.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes configurar idioma español en Laravel, ve directamente al archivo config/app.php y busca la línea que diga locale. Ahí simplemente la cambias por un “es“.

Si tienes laravel 8 con Jetstream y Fortify debes de instalar el paquete con composer:

```
composer require laravel-lang/lang:~7.0
```

Una vez hayas instalado la versión correcta para tu proyecto sólo debes de seleccionar los paquetes de idiomas que necesitas desde el directorio vendor/laravel-lang/lang y arrastrarlos al directorio resources/lang de tu proyecto.

Este repositorio esta para la versiones de laravel desde la 4, pero esta el repositorio de laravel para versiones de larabel >=5.8 y se llama Laraveles/spanish puedes ver todo el contenido [Laraveles/spanish](https://github.com/Laraveles/spanish)

Simplemente podrás actualizar y traducir tu App laravel en simples pasos y sin modificar uno por uno en el archivo de validation.php.